# Change Data Extension Nullable attribute to Required

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a data extension that has a "Nullable" field, that needs to be changed to "Required" (Not-Nullable), however the interface doesn't allow me to change it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

The typical **Email > Data Extensions** view doesn't allow you to change a nullable field back to required.

However, you can us the **Contact Builder > Data Extensions** interface to make more advanced edits to existing data extensions. For some reason, by default it doesn't like to change nullable fields, however you can trick it by adding a **default value** during the process...

**To change a field to "required" in a Data Extension:**

1. In the Data Extension properties screen, Click the edit symbol on the right of the field you want to edit.
2. Tick the "Required" field, add a value in the "Default Value" field, then click Save.
3. The field should now read "Nullable: No".

If needed, go back into the field and remove the default value.

You can also use this process to create primary keys in existing data extensions. This can be dangerous if you don't know your data, so be careful and always backup before you make changes.