# Cannot delete or change the primary key column in Sendable DataExtension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, email-studio

We have a data extension with 2 attributes set as primary key. 
Now our requirement changed and we only need the primary key constraint on 1 attribute only.

But the system doesn't allow me to remove the primary key constraint on the second attribute once it is set up. I have deleted all the records in the DE but still, I cannot remove the primary key constraint on the second attribute. I can't even delete the attribute also.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These the primary key setting are immutable on data extensions (both in Email Studio and Contact Builder (although you can change fields to nullable/required in Contact Builder)

The best way to achieve it would be to create ( a clone), with only a primary key constraint on one of the keys.

**Resources:**

- [Change Data Extension Nullable attribute to Required](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173682/change-data-extension-nullable-attribute-to-required/173683#173683)